# Error: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427) when querying Infusionsoft API for email existence

Tags: infusionsoft

I am using Infusionsoft for managing contacts/tags via an API. When attempting to query if an email is already added, I sometimes encounter the following error:
**EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)**

What could be the issue, and how can it be fixed?